# Move data from google cloud storage to S3 using dataproc hadoop cluster and airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to transfer a large quantity of data from GCS to S3 bucket. I have spun up a hadoop cluster using Google DataProc.

I am able to run the job via the Hadoop CLI using the following:

```
hadoop distcp -update gs://GCS-bucket/folder s3a://[my_aws_access_id]:[my_aws_secret]@aws-bucket/folder
```

I am new to mapreduce and hadoop. I am trying to add this to my airflow workflow using the `DataProcHadoopOperator`:

```
export_to_s3 = DataProcHadoopOperator(
            task_id='export_to_s3',
            main_jar=None,
            main_class=None,
            arguments=None,
            archives=None,
            files=None,
            job_name='{{task.task_id}}_{{ds_nodash}}',
            cluster_name='optimize-m',
            dataproc_hadoop_properties=None,
            dataproc_hadoop_jars=None,
            gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
            delegate_to=None,
            region='global',
            dag=dag

  )
```

my airflow is dockerized running on a compute engine instance.

I'm not sure how to make it so that it creates the below as a job

```
hadoop distcp -update gs://GCS-bucket/folder s3a://[my_aws_access_id]:[my_aws_secret]@aws-bucket/folder
```

I have followed suggestions and have constructed the following airflow task:

```
export_to_s3 = DataProcHadoopOperator(
            task_id='export_to_s3',
            main_jar='file:///usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-distcp.jar',
            main_class=None,
            arguments='-update gs://umg-comm-tech-dev/data/apollo/QA/ s3a://[mys3accessid]:[mys3secret]@s3://umg-ers-analytics/qubole/user-data/pitched/optimize/QA/'.split(' '),
            archives=None,
            files=None,
            job_name='{{task.task_id}}_{{ds_nodash}}',
            cluster_name='optimize',
            dataproc_hadoop_properties=None,
            dataproc_hadoop_jars=None,
            gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
            delegate_to=None,
            region='global',
            dag=dag

  )
```

However I am now getting the following error:

```
18/01/18 10:13:42 INFO gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase: GHFS version: 1.6.2-hadoop2
18/01/18 10:13:42 WARN s3native.S3xLoginHelper: The Filesystem URI contains login details. This is insecure and may be unsupported in future.
18/01/18 10:13:43 WARN s3a.S3AFileSystem: Client: Amazon S3 error 400: 400 Bad Request; Bad Request (retryable)

com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 8F6A80AA7432A696), S3 Extended Request ID: U6j5J9djR5UPPjhbjjLOtn7dG4IXDyMZfTD6CuFk5V6MXdUP65ArF56zP4Okx2NScxqYVh/UCTI=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3785)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1107)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2812)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2831)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:462)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.shim.HadoopRunJarShim.main(HadoopRunJarShim.java:12)
18/01/18 10:13:43 ERROR tools.DistCp: Invalid arguments: 
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSS3IOException: doesBucketExist on s3: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 8F6A80AA7432A696), S3 Extended Request ID: U6j5J9djR5UPPjhbjjLOtn7dG4IXDyMZfTD6CuFk5V6MXdUP65ArF56zP4Okx2NScxqYVh/UCTI=: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 8F6A80AA7432A696)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2812)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2831)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:356)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.setTargetPathExists(DistCp.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:462)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.services.agent.job.shim.HadoopRunJarShim.main(HadoopRunJarShim.java:12)
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 8F6A80AA7432A696), S3 Extended Request ID: U6j5J9djR5UPPjhbjjLOtn7dG4IXDyMZfTD6CuFk5V6MXdUP65ArF56zP4Okx2NScxqYVh/UCTI=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3785)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.headBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1107)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExist(AmazonS3Client.java:1070)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:276)
    ... 18 more
Invalid arguments: doesBucketExist on s3: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 8F6A80AA7432A696), S3 Extended Request ID: U6j5J9djR5UPPjhbjjLOtn7dG4IXDyMZfTD6CuFk5V6MXdUP65ArF56zP4Okx2NScxqYVh/UCTI=: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: 8F6A80AA7432A696)
usage: distcp OPTIONS [source_path...] <target_path>
              OPTIONS
 -append                       Reuse existing data in target files and
                               append new data to them if possible
 -async                        Should distcp execution be blocking
 -atomic                       Commit all changes or none
 -bandwidth <arg>              Specify bandwidth per map in MB
 -delete                       Delete from target, files missing in source
 -diff <arg>                   Use snapshot diff report to identify the
                               difference between source and target
 -f <arg>                      List of files that need to be copied
 -filelimit <arg>              (Deprecated!) Limit number of files copied
                               to <= n
 -filters <arg>                The path to a file containing a list of
                               strings for paths to be excluded from the
                               copy.
 -i                            Ignore failures during copy
 -log <arg>                    Folder on DFS where distcp execution logs
                               are saved
 -m <arg>                      Max number of concurrent maps to use for
                               copy
 -mapredSslConf <arg>          Configuration for ssl config file, to use
                               with hftps://. Must be in the classpath.
 -numListstatusThreads <arg>   Number of threads to use for building file
                               listing (max 40).
 -overwrite                    Choose to overwrite target files
                               unconditionally, even if they exist.
 -p <arg>                      preserve status (rbugpcaxt)(replication,
                               block-size, user, group, permission,
                               checksum-type, ACL, XATTR, timestamps). If
                               -p is specified with no <arg>, then
                               preserves replication, block size, user,
                               group, permission, checksum type and
                               timestamps. raw.* xattrs are preserved when
                               both the source and destination paths are
                               in the /.reserved/raw hierarchy (HDFS
                               only). raw.* xattrpreservation is
                               independent of the -p flag. Refer to the
                               DistCp documentation for more details.
 -sizelimit <arg>              (Deprecated!) Limit number of files copied
                               to <= n bytes
 -skipcrccheck                 Whether to skip CRC checks between source
                               and target paths.
 -strategy <arg>               Copy strategy to use. Default is dividing
                               work based on file sizes
 -tmp <arg>                    Intermediate work path to be used for
                               atomic commit
 -update                       Update target, copying only missingfiles or
                               directories
```

Would really appreciate some help.

Thanks!

Comment: Figured out the issue -  `s3a://[mys3accessid]:[mys3secret]@s3://umg-ers-analytics/qubole/user-data/pitched/optimize/QA/'.split(' ')` should be `s3a://[mys3accessid]:[mys3secret]@umg-ers-analytics/qubole/user-data/pitched/optimize/QA/'.split(' ')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Airflow, but it looks like DataProcHadoopOperator is just a wrapper around `gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop`.

I believe `hadoop distcp` is just a wrapper around `hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-distcp.jar`, so submitting a distcp throught the Dataproc API would look like this:

`gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop --cluster=optimize --jar file:///usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-distcp.jar -- -update gs://GCS-bucket/folder s3a://[my_aws_access_id]:[my_aws_secret]@aws-bucket/folder`

So for airflow you probably want something like this:

`main_jar='file:///usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-distcp.jar',
arguments='-update gs://GCS-bucket/folder s3a://[my_aws_access_id]:[my_aws_secret]@aws-bucket/folder'.split(' '),`

FYI, your cluster argument to airflow is probably just `optimize` if `optimize-m` is the master VM name.

Comment: many thanks for your response, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, I am now having issues with Data proc access scopes, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Getting the following error: `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1/projects/umg-comm-tech-dev/regions/global/jobs:submit?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">`

Comment: I now fixed this issue using the issue with permissions but now I'm getting a new 400 error: `Invalid arguments: doesBucketExist on s3: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: BE216FD56726BC17), S3 Extended Request ID: +4+kP6JNAjucEdXsm7XWp6fmu9g7x+gKMoWX4nH6rOaZxK4LhHDGBBmEs9xbwGBHKNvE9Zvp7R0=: Bad Request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 400 Bad Request; Request ID: BE216FD56726BC17)
usage: distcp OPTIONS [source_path...] <target_path>`

Comment: Ah I've never used S3 so I can't really help with that. 400 implies it's a malformed request. Consider turning up debug logging if this is happening on the driver: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/driver-output#configuring_logging

Comment: FYI -- consider using an init action to set your AWS secrets in /etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml. That way, it's only in one place, rather than plumbed through multiple services.

Comment: To elaborate on what Karthik is saying, you should [set the keys](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) `fs.s3a.access.key` and `fs.s3a.secret.key` using an initialization action that calls something like `bdconfig set_property --configuration_file=/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml --name=fs.s3a.access.key --value=<your access key>` instead of using the inline syntax for your s3a:// paths. It's considered a best-practice guideline to limit the places you put credentials, and that way you don't need to inline credentials in airflow arguments.

Comment: Thanks for both of your suggestions re: init action to set my AWS secrets. I've investigated the `400 Bad Request error` further, it seems it is being caused  by incorrect arguments being past to `distcp`, I will update my question with code snippets. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using dataproc? Would not a gsutil command be simpler?

eg:

```
gsutil -m rsync -r gs://GCS s3://S3
```

Something like this would move your data from GCS to S3 notice the -m flag in there, it means that it will use parallel sync upload, you can also use other flags to delete at the origin as well -d.

Comment: already tried this but not suitable for the amount of data I need to move, I found it kept timing out

Comment: Humm from what I was able to understand distcp is normally used when your data is in HDFS, I'm assuming it's not the case as such gsutil or Storage Transfer Service are the more appropriate solutions https://cloud.google.com/storage/transfer/

Comment: You can also try a client like minio https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide#mirror